# Laravel Socialite 403 Forbidden error when redirect back

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, http-status-code-403, laravel-socialite

I am trying to log in with **Google+ API** in my website using Socialite package. but it is not working as expected. I am developing a website in Laravel. The API is working fine returning all data using JS but when I am trying to do this using Socialite, It showing 403 Forbidden Error page when redirecting back.

My Route:

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Redirect Method:

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->redirect();
}
```

Callback Method:

```
public function handleProviderCallbackd($provider)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->user();

    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);

    Auth::login($authUser, true);
    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}
```

I have tried to use stateless() method to avoid the error but it is not working.

**Note:** When it redirect back the URL has scope parameter, if I remove that parameter then it works fine.

Comment: Hi @Amit Do you found any solution, i am also looking this same issue.

Comment: Check this answer. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53348777/socialite-laravel-authantication-error-with-google-api/55782862#55782862

Comment: Now I am getting InvalidStateException error